# $\lim\sup$ of random variables a.s. converging to $\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Revisiting my Probability Theory book, I found an exercise in the chapter concerning the zero-one-law of Kolmogorov where it says

One proves the following: Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ independent random variables with $\mathbf{P}(X_n = -1)= \mathbf{P}(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$, let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n , n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $\lim\sup _{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ a.s.

Why can this be true and - more specifically - why is $\lim\sup _{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty$ almost sure when the individual random variables have equal chance of cancelling out each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no contradiction with the fact that "the random variables have equal chance of cancelling out each other". You don't have that $S_n$ almost surely goes to infinity, but only that its limsup is infinite. This just means that you reach arbitrarily large elements of $\mathbb{N}$. By the way, the same argument will show that $\liminf S_n=-\infty$, so again, there is no contradiction.

Now, first, you show that $P(\limsup S_n=+\infty)$ is 0 or 1. Indeed, the event $\limsup S_n=+\infty$ is the same as the event $\limsup (S_n-S_k)=+\infty$. But $S_n-S_k=X_{k+1}+...+X_{n}$, so this event is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{k+1}=\sigma (X_{k+1},X_{k+2},...)$.
This is true for all $k$, so by independence and by the 0-1 law, you have the conclusion.

Observe then that since the random variables are symmetric, the two events $\limsup S_n=+\infty$ and $\liminf S_n=-\infty$ have the same probability (which is 0 or 1). To conclude, you just need to prove that the random walk is almost surely not bounded. This will mean that $P(\limsup S_n=+\infty \cup \liminf S_n=-\infty)=1$ and will thus give you the result you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "by independence" in the 2nd paragraph? Independence of the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F_{k}$? They aren't independent. Neither, I think, are the $S_n$.

Comment: No but the $X_k$ are independent.

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}=\bigcap \mathcal{F}_k$ is the tail $\sigma$-algebra of the $X_k$. The Kolmogorov's 0-1 law states that if the $X_k$ are independent, then $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Note given *any* random variables $(Y_n)_{n \geq 1}$, we have that $Y^* := \limsup Y_n$ and $Y_* := \liminf Y_n$ are both $\mathcal T((Y_n)_{n \geq 1})$-measurable. By the Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law, given any $m \in \mathbb N$, $\mathbb P[Y^* \geq m] \in \{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb P[Y_* \leq -m] \in \{0,1\}$.

Consider the event $A_m := \{S^* \leq m\} \cap \{S_* \geq -m\}$.

**Claim:** $\mathbb P[A_m] = 0$ for every $m \geq 1$. (Proven below.)

If this claim is true, it follows that
$$
\mathbb P\left[ \left\{ S^* > m\right\} \cup \left\{ S_* < -m\right\}\right] = 1.
$$
Note $\mathbb P\left[ S^* > m\right] = \mathbb P\left[S_* < -m \right]$. Indeed, $\mathbb P\left[S_* < -m\right] = \mathbb P\left[ -(S_*) > m\right] = \mathbb P\left[(-S)^* > m\right] = \mathbb P\left[S^* > m\right]$, where $(-S)^* = \limsup (-S_n)$, since $S_n$ and $-S_n$ are equivalently distributed. So, since $\mathbb P\left[S^* > m\right] \in \{0,1\}$, 
$$
1 = \mathbb P\left[ \left\{ S^* > m\right\} \cup \left\{ S_* < -m\right\}\right] \leq \mathbb P\left[  S^* > m\right] + \mathbb P\big[S_* < -m\big] = 2\mathbb P\left[S^* > m\right] \in \{0,2\}.
$$
Therefore $\mathbb P\left[S^* > m\right] = 1$ for every $m \geq 1$. Since $\{S^* = \infty\} = \mathop \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \{S^* > m\}$ and $\{S^* > m\} \supset \{S^* > m+1\}$ for every $m$, by upper semicontinuity of probability measures, $\mathbb P\left[ S^* = \infty \right] = 1$.

**Proof of Claim.** Note that
\begin{equation}
A_m = \mathop\bigcup_{k= 1}^\infty \mathop \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty \{|S_n| \leq m \} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
In order for $\mathop \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty \{|S_n| \leq m \}$ to occur, no $2m+1$ consecutive $X_n$'s can be the same for $n \geq k$. Indeed, if for some $\ell \geq 1$ we have $X_\ell = X_{\ell+1} = \cdots = X_{\ell+2m} = 1$, the sum of these random variables is $2m+1$, and if $S_{\ell-1} = -m$, we'd have $S_{\ell+2m} = m+1$, contradiction. In particular, 
$$
\mathop \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty \big\{|S_n| \leq m \big\} \subset \ \mathop\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \big\{ X_{k+(2m+1)n}, X_{k+(2m+1)n+1}, \ldots, X_{k+(2m+1)n+2m} \textrm{ are not all $-1$ or $1$} \big\} \tag{2}
$$
Note the events in the intersection on the right side of the above statement each involve different random variables. In particular, these events are independent since $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is independent. There are $2^{2m+1}$ possible arrangements of any collection of $2m+1$ $\mathrm{Rad}_{1/2}$-distributed random variables; e.g. for $m=1$, we could have $(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (1,1,1)$ or $(1,1,-1)$ or $(1,-1,1)$, etc., with $2^3 = 8$ possible arrangements. If the $\mathrm{Rad}_{1/2}$ random variables are independent, each of these arrangements occurs with the same probability of $2^{-2m-1}$. Each event $\left\{ X_{k+(2m+1)n}, X_{k+(2m+1)n+1}, \ldots, X_{k+(2m+1)n+2m} \textrm{ are not all $-1$ or $1$} \right\}$ allows any arrangement of $2m+1$ $\mathrm{Rad}_{1/2}$ random variables, except two: the arrangements of all $1$s and of all $-1$s. Therefore, 
$$
\mathbb P\big[X_{k+(2m+1)n}, X_{k+(2m+1)n+1}, \ldots, X_{k+(2m+1)n+2m} \textrm{ are not all $-1$ or $1$} \big] = \frac{2^{2m+1}-2}{2^{2m+1}}
$$
By independence of the events on the right side of (2), we get: 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P \left[ \mathop \bigcap_{n=k}^\infty \big\{|S_n| \leq m \big\}\right] &\leq \prod_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P\big[X_{k+(2m+1)n}, X_{k+(2m+1)n+1}, \ldots, X_{k+(2m+1)n+2m} \textrm{ are not all $-1$ or $1$} \big] \\
&= \prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2m+1}-2}{2^{2m+1}} = 0.
\end{align}
By $\sigma$-subadditivity, (1) now gives us 
$$
\mathbb P\left[ \left\{ S^* \leq m \right\} \cap \left\{ S_* \geq -m \right\}\right] = 0.
$$
QED.

Comment: It appears you made a typo in your two fractions because the infinite product over constants in n surely isn't 0

Comment: Surely it is, if those constants are $<1$.

Comment: yeah, I'm dumb, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It might help first to think about what the distribution of $S_n$ is. The central limit theorem implies it looks roughly like a normal with mean zero and variance $\sqrt{n}.$ So sure, zero is the most likely value here, but the fluctuations keep growing as $n$ increases.

Here is a picture of 100 paths of $S_n$ for $n$ up to 1000.
[image]

Notice that the paths are all roughly contained within a square root envelope. Essentially, the paths $S_n$ "wander" within this envelope. This isn't a proof of this fact (or even a precise statement of it), but hopefully seeing the picture makes it more plausible.

$\limsup_n S_n=\infty$ means that for any $k\in \mathbb Z,$ we will have $S_n>k$ infinitely many times. This is consistent with, and in fact expected from the behavior I described.

Comment: Nice picture. But I don't think you need to use precise description of the behaviour  of $S_n$ as you do to prove that it is oscillating.

Comment: @M.Dus I didn’t give a precise picture, though I was certainly hinting at law of iterated logarithm. And you’re certainly right that that is way more than is needed to get that the limsup is infinity a.s. It was more to give an intuition for how random walks work, so that the result seems plausible.

Comment: Yes of course and your picture certainly gives a nice intuition.